# Excel function to determine the last Friday in a month

Tags: excel, datetime

I'm looking for an Excel function to return the last Friday in a month for a given date.

ie: Any date in the month as input will give the date of the last Friday as output.

```
14-July-09 should give 31-July-09
7-March-05 should give 35-March-09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following formula achives this for a date in cell A1:

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0)+MOD(-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,0),2)-2,-7)
```

Answer (score 6):

Building on `@Toomas` answer above, I had to make some amendments for Excel 2007, but came up with the following:

```
=EOMONTH(A1,0)-MOD(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A1,0))+1,7)
```

Which is assuming that the `WEEKDAY` returned for Friday is 6 and then applying a shifted `MOD 7` to achieve the correct day.

Answer (score 3):

Try this formula:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A5;0);16)=7;EOMONTH(A5;0);EOMONTH(A5;0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A5;0);16))
```

Enter to A5 date value of which you are looking for the last Friday in a month.

Answer (score 1):

I came here looking for the formula to get the most recent Friday in the past which turned out to be `=TODAY()-WEEKDAY(TODAY())-1`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
=DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-1+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(A1),MONTH(A1)+1,1)-1),-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,0,-1)
```

to find the last friday of the month. Assumes A1 has the date.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone needs to do this for next year (or future years):

```
=EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(TODAY()),1),0)-MOD(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())+1,MONTH(TODAY()),1),0))+1,7)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that will show the last Friday of the current month.

And if the date is in the past it will show you next month's last Friday.

And if it's December right now, it'll show you next year's January's Friday.

```
=IF(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0)+MOD(-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0),2)-2,-7)>=TODAY(), DATE(IF(MONTH(TODAY())+1>12,YEAR(TODAY()+1),YEAR(TODAY())),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0)+MOD(-WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0),2)-2,-7), DATE(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=12,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())),MONTH(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=12,1,MONTH(TODAY())))+1,0)+MOD(-WEEKDAY(DATE(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=12,YEAR(TODAY())+1,YEAR(TODAY())),MONTH(IF(MONTH(TODAY())=12,1,MONTH(TODAY())))+1,0),2)-2,-7))
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey the formatting is outdated so ill show what I came up with:

```
=EOMONTH(A1;A2)-(WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(A1;A2);15)-1)
```

`[A1]` is an interval of months later, from `[A2]` the stating date, that the result date should be.

*We have some equipment that need maintenance last Friday of the month, an number of months since last Maintenace.*

`EOMONTH(A1;A2)`: we find the date, of the last day, of target month.
`WEEKDAY([Date];15)`: assign a number for day of the week.
`[15]` makes Friday the value 1 and Thursday the value 7.

so if the last day of the month is Friday, the calculation would be:

**[Date]-(1-1) = [Date]** therefor the date won't change.
***[Date]** in my original code example, is the last day of the target month: `[A2]` date + `[A1]` number of months later.*

if the last day is Wednesday, we want it to subtract 5 days: **[Date]-(6-1) = [Date]-5**

As a sidenote:

```
=WORKDAY(A2+1;-1;[hollydays])
```

will round a date back to the earlier Workday if it lands in a weekend or holyday
[holyday] can be an area of cells with predefined dates to skip eg: `[$C$1:$C$20]`.

$ is so the area won't change when you extend the function to other cells.

if you don't care about holydays use `=WORKDAY(A2+1;-1)`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A universal formula to find any rank of a weekday in a month would be:

```
DATE(year,month,MOD(weekdayWanted−WEEKDAY(DATE(year,month,1),2),7)+1)+DURATION(weekShift,dayShift)
```

where:

- weekdayWanted is 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, etc.
- weekShift is the week difference between the first occurrence of a specific weekday to the one desired
- dayShift is the day difference between the Xth weekday of the month and another day of the week
- year, month and the three other values can be constants, references or formulas, of course.
- DURATION can be omitted if you're only interested in the first occurence in the month

So if you're looking for the last Friday of September 2023 (which is the first Friday of October minus one week), you'd use

```
DATE(2023,10,MOD(5−WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,10,1),2),7)+1)+DURATION(-1)
```

If you're looking for the Wednesday following the second Sunday of March 2023 (which is not the same than the second Wednesday), you'd use

```
DATE(2023,3,MOD(7−WEEKDAY(DATE(2023,3,1),2),7)+1)+DURATION(1,3)
```

- weekdayWanted = 7 (Sunday)
- weekShift = 1 (second Sunday)
- dayShift = 3 (Wednesday - Sunday)

Answer (score -1):

Awesome!  Basically, like trying to find the first or second Monday of the month,

```
=DATE(TheYear,5,1)+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(TheYear,5,1)),1,0,6,5,4,3,2)
```

which returns the first Monday of the month, in this case May

but to find the *last* weekday of the month, in the formula, you start with the next month and subtract

```
=DATE(TheYear,6,1)-1+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(TheYear,6,1)),-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0)
```

which returns the last Monday of May

I have a cell that I named TheYear, in which I enter the year I'm working with, but you can point to whatever cell you have the year you want (e.g. A1).

I don't know why the pointers to the days of the week are in reverse order but to find the day (e.g. Tuesday instead of Monday), change the order of those numbers but they have to stay in order.  For example, 4th Thursday of November:

```
=DATE(TheYear,11,1)+21+CHOOSE(WEEKDAY(DATE(TheYear,11,1)),4,3,2,1,0,6,5)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
=EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)-WEEKDAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))-1
```

This gives the last Friday of this month. You can replace both instances of `Today()` with any date you like or a cell reference that has a date to get the last Friday in any other month.

Answer (score -1):

=WORKDAY.INTL((EOMONTH(A4,0)+1),-1,"1111011")

Comment: You could add some details. That "1111011" constant looks suspicious

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).